# Is there any option in flutter to print a receipt on button click in device built in printer

Tags: flutter, dart, printing, printers

i have an android phone this phone has built in printer, i tried [Printing](https://pub.dev/packages/printing) package it is working but is launching some other screen for pdf to view and select options etc. what i want is to print the receipt directly on button click, is there any package or something that can do printing directly, any help will be appreciated thank you.

On print button i am navigating to this screen

```
    // import 'dart:typed_data';

import 'dart:typed_data';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:pdf/pdf.dart';
import 'package:pdf/widgets.dart' as pw;
import 'package:printing/printing.dart';

class PrintingOrderReceipt extends StatelessWidget {
  const PrintingOrderReceipt(this.title);

  final String title;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text(title)),
        body: PdfPreview(
          build: (format) => _generatePdf(format, title),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<Uint8List> _generatePdf(PdfPageFormat format, String title) async {
    final pdf = pw.Document();

    pdf.addPage(
      pw.Page(
        pageFormat: format,
        build: (context) {
          return pw.Center(
            child: pw.Text('This is just for testing'),
          );
        },
      ),
    );

    return pdf.save();
  }
}
```

Comment: Share your code please

Comment: @VadimPopov i added the code , please look into the updated question, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Printing is a system-based function that **requires** user input. Printing means different things to different people (ie. create & save a pdf, create & save an image, send to a multitude of connected printers via network, etc.) so a prompt is necessary.

I doubt you will find any programmatic solution.